# Getting error of: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a register page, and when the user registers, it should go to the home page, then display a message.

The way I implemented it is the following:

- app.js has a state called message
- In the return statement, I added `message && <div>{message}</div>`
- When the user clicks on submit, setMessage is called, (passed down via props) and the message should change
- Redirects to the home page, which has `useEffect(() => {}, [props.location.pathname.split('/')[1]])`

When I run the application, I get the following error:

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it? Here's the full code:

**app.js**

```
const [message, setMessage] = useState({});

return (
    <div className='App'>
        {message && message.text && (
            <div>{message.text}</div>
        )}
        <Switch>
            <Route
                path='register'
                component={props => (
                    <Register setMessage={setMessage}/>
                )}
            />
            <Route
                path='/'
                component={({ location }) => (
                    <MainContent
                        location={location}
                    />
                )}
            />
        </Switch>
    </div>
);
```

**register.js**

```
const [shouldRedirect, setShouldRedirect] = useState(false);
const submitCallback = async credidentials => {
    try {
        // Post Data...
        const message = { text: 'You Registered' };
        setMessage(message);
        setShouldRedirect(true);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};

return (
    {shouldRedirect && <Redirect to='/' />}
)
```

**Home.jsx**

```
useEffect(() => {
    //FetchData
}, [urlPath]);
```

Comment: It's because of your async submit call. Here are some examples of how to handle this - https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data/

Comment: @Dom Thanks for you input! I went through that article, and I didn't find anywhere were he wrote about this error. Do you mind screenshoting it? Also, when I remove  `setMessage(message)`, then it works well

Comment: Note that `<route>` has both the component and render props, you should only pass "stable" components to the component function, and only pass functions to the render prop, this prevents lots of unmounting and remounting problems

Comment: What do you mean by stable components?